# Excel formula to return value from another column if there are cells matching in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns like below

```
ID          Qty
FW01        20
AW08        100
FW01        30
FW01        40
AW55        60
```

I need the formula to search in the column ID and find all similar cells in this columns
and return the biggest value from Qty column which matches this ID,
In the previous example, the result will be 40.

Comment: Office 365 has MAXIFS.

Comment: Define similar. `AW08` is arguably similar to `AW55`. Do you mean equal (as your example seems to indicate)?

Comment: so your output would be for only `FW01`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MAXIFS:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,"FW01")
```

Or:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,B2:B6/(A2:A6 = "FW01"),1)
```

Or the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A6 = "FW01",B2:B6))
```

Using Ctrl-Shift-Enter on Exit from Edit mode.

Or simply use a Pivot table:

[image]